# Nx converter to ESLint's flat config breaks linting

Tags: nrwl-nx, typescript-eslint, eslintrc, eslint-flat-config

#### Problem

After using `nx g @nx/eslint:convert-to-flat-config` described [here](https://nx.dev/recipes/tips-n-tricks/flat-config) I got **automatically generated** config files like this (example for a library named "not-found"):

```js
const { FlatCompat } = require('@eslint/eslintrc');
const baseConfig = require('../../eslint.config.js');
const js = require('@eslint/js');
const compat = new FlatCompat({
  baseDirectory: __dirname,
  recommendedConfig: js.configs.recommended,
});
module.exports = [
  ...baseConfig,
  ...compat
    .config({
      extends: [
        'plugin:@nx/angular',
        'plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates',
      ],
    })
    .map((config) => ({
      ...config,
      files: ['libs/not-found/**/*.ts'],
      rules: {
        '@angular-eslint/directive-selector': [
          'error',
          {
            type: 'attribute',
            prefix: 'npp',
            style: 'camelCase',
          },
        ],
        '@angular-eslint/component-selector': [
          'error',
          {
            type: 'element',
            prefix: 'npp',
            style: 'kebab-case',
          },
        ],
      },
    })),
  ...compat
    .config({
      plugins: ['deprecation'],
      parserOptions: { project: 'libs/not-found/tsconfig.*?.json' },
    })
    .map((config) => ({
      ...config,
      files: ['libs/not-found/**/*.ts'],
      rules: { 'deprecation/deprecation': 'warn' },
    })),
  ...compat
    .config({ extends: ['plugin:@nx/angular-template'] })
    .map((config) => ({
      ...config,
      files: ['libs/not-found/**/*.html'],
      rules: {},
    })),
];
```

Now executing the command `nx run not-found:lint` produces following error:

```
Linting "not-found"...

Error: You have attempted to use the lint rule deprecation/deprecation which requires the full TypeScript type-checker to be available, but you do not have `parserOptions.project` configured to point at your project tsconfig.json files in the relevant TypeScript file "overrides" block of your project ESLint config /path/to/my/monorepo/libs/not-found/eslint.config.js

Please see https://nx.dev/guides/eslint for full guidance on how to resolve this issue.
```

This problem occurs to all apps and libs inside the monorepo now. There is no working-scenario, with which i could compare.

#### Investigation

I visited the referenced link, but the docs there refer to the old eslintrc config format.

I am confused as to why the error message mentions a 'relevant TypeScript file "overrides" block'. The [Nx docs](https://nx.dev/recipes/tips-n-tricks/flat-config) say that overrides are no longer used:

> use a flat cascading of rules (instead of a mix of rules and overrides)

The referenced [official migration guide](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/migration-guide) supports this impression.

I googled the error message, but the only solutions I found referred to the old eslintrc format and suggested adding the `parserOptions.project` property in the overrides block. But this was already there in my configs and is still there after the conversion, as you can see in the source-code i posted.

[image]

#### Question

**What steps do i have to take, to complete the conversion to a flat config format and have the nx lint command working again?**